# HTML - selectedindexchanged of dropdown not working for the second time

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the code where the image should be displayed on changing the value of the dropdownlist --

```
<html>
 <head><title>Image Display</title></head>
   <script type = "text/JavaScript">
        function displayImage() {
        var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
        var index = dropdown1.options[dropdown1.selectedIndex].value;
    //alert(index);

    var img = new Image();  
    if(index == 0){
        img.src = "D:\\Images\\LamborghiniLaunche.png"
        imgDiv.appendChild(img);
    }   
    else if(index == 1){
        img.src = "D:\\Images\\Nano.JPG"
        imgDiv.appendChild(img);
    }
    else if(index == 2){
        img.src = "D:\\Images\\bmw-i8.jpg"
        imgDiv.appendChild(img);
     }
  }
  </script>
  <body>
<select id="dropdown1" name ="select" onchange="displayImage();">
    <option selected disabled>Select here</option>
    <option value ="0">Lamborghini Launche
    <option value ="1">Nano
    <option value ="2">BMW i8
    </option>
    </select>

<div id="imgDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem:
After selecting the dropdown value for the first time, it loads the corresponding image successfully but changing the drop-down value for the second time fails to loads the corresponding image.

Comment: do you want to display image on div or do you want to append?

Comment: Just 1 remark, in your select-tag, in the onchange event, you can't place a ';' behind the displayImage() method. The code will not work if you do this.

Comment: i want to add a new image on every change of dropdown value.

Comment: @Chirag so if you select from drop down menu 5 times there should be total 5 images inside div?or 1 image?

Comment: @Cedric removed ';' behind displayImage()  Still no change in output

Comment: @FastSnail while changing dropdown value, s it not possible to replace the existing image with the new image in the same div ?

Comment: @Chirag it's possible .check dfsq answer .isn't it you want

Comment: @Chirag no, I know, dfsq probaly has the solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to create and addend new images on every option change. It may be that due to your styles you simply don't see new image, because it's after the first one.

Instead create image if it doesn't exist and change its `src` if it's already there. Something like this:

```js
function displayImage() {
    var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
    var index = dropdown1.options[dropdown1.selectedIndex].value;

    var imgDiv = document.querySelector('#imgDiv img');
    if (!imgDiv) {
        imgDiv = new Image();
        document.querySelector('#imgDiv').appendChild(imgDiv);
    }
    
    if (index == 0) {
        imgDiv.src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/1";
    } else if (index == 1) {
        imgDiv.src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/2"
    } else if (index == 2) {
        imgDiv.src = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food/3";
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown1" name="select" onchange="displayImage();">
    <option selected disabled>Select here</option>
    <option value="0">Lamborghini Launche</option>
    <option value="1">Nano</option>
    <option value="2">BMW i8</option>
</select>
<div id="imgDiv"></div>
```

Comment: New to JS. Is it always that guys in JS answer with images of food? This is the 4th answer I'm seeing today with food images

Comment: I chose food because it's easy to type in lorempixel.com image category. Why others, no idea :)

Comment: Lol! Got it. Learning JS. When I start answering I'll also start using pics of food. :)